# Jquery Replace with Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am attempting to do what so many have tried.  that is to load a Child DIV and Replace the present DIV.  People have suggested using x.load(y > *)  but when I use the Star in IE it fails to load the page where as in chrome it loads fine.

Does anyone know what I should do to wrap this so that it works with IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *load* a DIV, you *create* one using;

```
var aNewDiv = $('<div />');
```

You can then replace your div using the [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) method;

```
x.replaceWith(aNewDiv);
```

If you want to load an element from another page, you can do;

```
x.load('foo.html .selector', function () {
    var self = $(this);

    self.replaceWith(self.children());
});
```

For more info, see the [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load) documentation.